# iOS app - SQLite pre-loaded database not properly loading, cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

**EDIT:** I tried by-passing Ionic View and testing through Xcode to make sure the problem was with Ionic View and not something else. The code worked as intended on an iPad when tested through Xcod, so it seems that if you're using a plugin not on [this short list](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage) of View compatible plugins it won't work.

**Original Question:**

I am currently testing using SQLite as a backend database for mobile, and the functionality I'm looking for (using pre-loaded database and displaying a number of entries in the UI) is working in the iOS emulator but not on the actual device. I'm viewing it on the device using Ionic View.

**app.js**

```
var db = null;


var example = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

example.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $window) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("database.db", 2, function() {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "database.db", location: 'default'});
      $window.alert("db copy success");
    }, function(error) {
      console.error("app.js::onReady - Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "database.db", location: 'default'});
      $window.alert("db copy failure");
    });

  });
})
```

**controllers.js**

```
example.controller("testCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaSQLite, $window) {

$scope.results = [];

$scope.test = function() {
    $window.alert("Test");
}

$scope.select = function(name) {
    //console.log(db.tables);
    $window.alert("testCtrl::select - Called");
    var query = "SELECT name FROM clinic WHERE country = ?";
    try {
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [name]).then(function(res) {
        $window.alert("testCtrl::select/execute - Called");
        if(res.rows.length > 0) {
          for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.results.push({name: res.rows.item(i).name}); 
          }         
        } else {
          console.log("No results found.");
          $window.alert("No results found");
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("controller.js::select - Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        $window.alert("controller.js::select - Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
    } catch(error) {
      $window.alert(error);
    }   
  }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-item ng-click="select('Canada')">Select</ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-click="test()">Destroy</ion-item>

    <ion-item class="item-divider">Test List</ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="x in results track by $index">{{x.name}}</ion-item>

  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the app with Ionic View and hit select, it should print out the names of the first 5 clinics from Canada. The alerts tell me that the **select()** function in the **testCtrl** gets called, but apparently it gets called on a null. So the database isn't getting copied/opened. The alerts inside the **window.sqlDB.copy()** block aren't getting called at all.

I've tried wrapping that block in a **$timeout** but that didn't help.

The exact error that I get is:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n.transaction')
```

Comment: Are you using `cordova-plugin-dbcopy` ? It doesn't seem to be available in Ionic View according to the doc : http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage

Comment: I am using it yea, to copy the pre-populated database that I have into device storage. Are those the only plugins that will work in ionic view ? That seems pretty useless if you can't actually test how your app will function in view if it only supports a handful of plugins.

Comment: This is because you can still build your app by your own. With `ionic run ios` for example.

Comment: Using `ionic run ios` will bring it up in the emulator, I'm trying to test on device. So running the emulator doesn't help, because the `window.plugins.sqlDB.copy()` is working on the emulator.

Comment: To test on a device you can add the `--device` option.